# With DNS, what is the difference between Delegation, Forwarding, Conditional Forwarding, and Stub zones?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone, delegation

I am surprised at how many different ways I have read answers to this question and I still don't know the fine differences of the answer.

For each of these similar DNS concepts:

- Delegation
- Forwarding
- Conditional Forwarding
- Stub Zones

I would like a step-by-step layout of the life of a typical query, preferably "happy path" (query succeeds) and "sad path"(query fails due to a relevant misconfiguration).

In each step:

- "Who"(or what) is participating? (e.g. authoritative servers? caching servers? dual-purpose servers? clients? example domains/IPs preferred)
- What is the raw information being sent in the query? (i.e. a domain? an IP? whose is it? Where FROM and TO is it being sent in this step?)
- What and where is information being stored? (e.g. server only stores certain records

I prefer pictures with important details embedded.

Lastly, a summary of why you would use each concept/method over the others would be nice.

Comment: You're mixing terms that are associated with recursive and authoritative DNS. Unless you feel confidant that you understand the difference, answers that you get here aren't going to be very helpful: you're in need of a book.

Answer (score 5):

Watki02,

That is quite an ask. I tried to answer your question, but I think some more research on your part might be in order ;)

You are asking less of a question and more for a class on how DNS works.

I did not provide pictures, but if you read my answer they should be easy for you to make.

**Delegation**

Take domain.com. For the purpose of this discussion you registerd domain.com with GoDaddy. You have a website hosted by another company. Your website is www.domain.com.

You have decided that you want your zone file to be hosted by the same company that hosts your website content.

By default, your zone file is hosted where your domain is registered. For you to have the server that hosts your website content host your zone file you would login to GoDaddy and configure DNS delegation. That would require you to enter the Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN) of the name servers provided by the company that is hosting your website content.

When someone queries www.domain.com the request goes to GoDaddy who says you need to contact the name servers of the company that hosts the website content. GoDaddy provides the records for the name servers.

The query then obtains the information from the name servers that were specified.

**Forwarding**

DNS forwarding is something that a DNS server with forwarding configured does.

For our discussion we will say your internal domain name is network.com. If a computer in your network asks for server.network.com, your DNS server in your office that is the authoritative server for network.com will resolve the request. If a computer in your network asks for www.example.com, the request will first go to your DNS server in your office and the DNS server will say, I do not have any information for example.com, so you need to go to an external DNS server. The external DNS server is the forwarder.

So your DNS server in your office (ns.network.com) manages the zone file for network.com. If a request is made for something in the domain network.com ns.network.com is going to do the resolution. If a request is made for a zone that ns.network.com does not manage then ns.network.com says I don't know anything about the domain you need records to but here is the DNS forwarder that you need to get the records from. So if Google is your DNS forwarder then the request would be forwarded to Google. Google would then process the resolution request and provide a response.

**Conditional Forwarding**

Conditional forwarding is similar to forwarding except instead of forwarding all DNS requests that the DNS server cannot resolve to an external DNS server it only forwards DNS requests for specific domains.

So let's say you have a DNS server in your office (ns.network.com) and it has a DNS forwarder 8.8.8.8 (this is the public IP address for a Google public DNS server) but you want DNS requests for client.com to go to ns.client.com, then you would create a conditional forwarder that says DNS requests for client.com go to ns.client.com. If you do that even though ns.network.com cannot resolve desktop.client.com it will not be forwarded to Google but it will be forwarded to ns.client.com.

**Stub Zone**

A Stub Zone is a DNS zone file that contains the bare minimum DNS records so it can respond to queries. Usually a Stub Zone has a Start of Authority (SOA) record and Name Server (NS) records. This is useful if you have two different DNS servers each managing a zone and the two DNS servers need to talk with each other so each network can communicate with the other using internal DNS.

You can read more about DNS on the following pages:

[How DNS Query Works: Domain Name System (DNS)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775637%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

[Using forwarders: Domain Name System (DNS)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757172%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

[Understanding stub zones: Domain Name System (DNS)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779197%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: The ironic thing is that I am taking a training on DNS and that is how I thought to ask the question. I'll answer it for myself (and everyone else) the way I was thinking once I know the answer(s).

Comment: If you read my answer, I suspect you will find that a number of your questions are answered.

Comment: Some inaccuracies. 

Delegation: Godaddy would never be involved in the lookup. For a full recursive lookup you would 1st, goto the root name servers, then the .com ones, then finally the authoritative one for domain.com. Delegation is the where you say if you want anything in this subdomain got get it from these name servers. So the resolution path is

. -> com -> domain.com

The only place where godaddy will be mentioned is as the registrar in the whois information.

Comment: Forwarding: This is where all requests that the office server is not authoritative for are pushed to another dns server to fully resolve. This can be external, and usually is but doesn't have to be. You would usually do this to benefit from large scale caching and other services which are better catered for upstream. The forwarding DNS is the office one not the remote one, that is the recursive dns server.

Comment: You can also configure the office dns server to do fully recursive lookups as well and not use the upstream recursive server. This will add load and you wont benefit from having caches warmed. However is you want secure validated DNS lookups using DNSSEC you need to do this to verify the validity of the lookups, at least at this point in time.